# Error correction : It was not clear from the manual of instructions whether it should be signed or not

Tags: exam-questions

> It was not clear (A)/ from the manual of instructions (B) whether it should (C)/ be signed or not.(D)

This is an error correction question from my book. I thought the correction was either to omit *manual of* or to omit *of instructions* but my book suggests to replace *was* by *is*. Is the suggestion by book correct ?  If yes what would be correct sentence if I were to say the above sentence in past tense ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book is right! How? Refer C and D! It talks about the present tense.

> It <del>was</del> is not clear from the manual of instructions whether it should be signed or not.

If you were to say this in past, here it goes:

> It was not clear from the manual of instructions whether it *was to be* signed or not.

Comment: That may very well be what OP's book has in mind, but it's wrong. *Should* employed as a present realis has the same form in past tense; for example, *He thought he should go*.

Comment: @StoneyB what could be the answer then, sir?

Comment: The only change I would make is *manual of instructions* > *instruction manual*.

Comment: @stoneyb that even I thought but then I didnt think that as an error. Is it an error?